# usb_string from user space in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, usb

I have a USB Device with the following string present in the string descriptor table:

```
Index 0:                Standard              Language            0x0409 (English)
Index 1:                Standard              Manufacturer        "xxx Corporation"
Index 2:                Standard              Product             "xxx Board HID Device"
Index 3:                Custom                Sector              "Bootloader" or "Application" (depending on current mode of operation).
```

I want to read the string at Index 3. For Windows, we have an API 
`HidD_GetIndexedString()` which allows to get the string at any Index. What is the corresponding API in Linux? I see the driver is using `usb_string` to get the string in drivers but do we have any similar userspace API for usb in Linux?

Comment: [libusb](https://libusb.info/) has [libusb_get_string_descriptor](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/libusb/libusb.h#L1813).